# UV Mapping reset error

Tags: uv

I have this swimming pool mapped with just one texture.
When I try to reset the UV Map I get a strange triangles (image 1). If I unwrap it again I got only the swimming pool stairs (image 2).

The object was exported from MAX into 3DS in order I could open it in Blender. Might be a export bug?

Is there a way to fully reset the mesh or check if there some error?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: If the mesh is composed by tris only and you reset the uv, it's expected to obtain multiple-overlapping-tris-shaped islands. About the second part, maybe some faces are not sharing vertices/edges: did you try to remove doubles?

Comment: Yes, I've tried removed doubles but 0 vertices removed. Any advice?

Comment: Did you set an appropriate threshold value? Did you try to move the faces? Are they all "connected"? Do you have any edge marked as "seam"? Consider the option to upload your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for a faster resolution of the mystery.

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1984" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1984/)

Comment: I read that the model comes with a texture: are you trying to use a previously made UV, or make it on your own?

Answer (score 1):

### Watertight surfaces can't be unwrapped in one time without seams

The issue comes from the absence of any seam in the portion of mesh that not belong to the pool's stairs. As there is no edge marked as seam, you are asking the software to unwrap a shape that is "solid", that cannot be profitably unwrapped, an operation that leads to the "default" result (the same you get when choosing the *reset* function).

[image]

That is true even for simple object like the shown pyramid. You simply cannot unwrap watertight mesh (unless the are bi-dimensional): you need at least to make an hole somewhere or, preferrably, mark some seams:

[image]

Here's a possible result using the provided mesh:
[image]

Seams has been made all around the floor of the pool (on both sides) and the resulting ring has been cut in half at some point.

[image]

Comment: To help support that this isn't an error, when you unwrap any of the primitive meshes, you can get anything from a square to a triangle to a circle. If you plan to unwrap little by little and you need this stuff out of the way, you can either just move it somewhere or scale all the UVs to zero before you start. If you haven't moved the 2D cursor in the UV/Image editor, all the UVs should be at (0,0) when scaled to 0.